# Highcharts - y-axis data label missing in Firefox

Tags: highcharts

The following chart is missing the data label on the stacked column furthest to the right. The label appears correctly in latest version of Google Chrome, however the label does not appear in the latest version of Firefox.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 5]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 1]
        }]
    });
});
```

`Highcharts 3.0.5`

`Google Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m`

`Mozilla Firefox 21.0`

`Windows 7`

Is there a way to make the label appear consistently between the two browsers?
I am looking for a workaround that does not involve changing the height of the chart, or the data in the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/eGW86/1/

Comment: I have Firefox 21.0 for Mac and the data labels are appearing correctly for me.  Just to be sure, are you talking about the 8,2,5,and 1's on the Banana's column?

Comment: I have Firefox 24 on Win 7 and I also do not see the "1" in the right most column. However, it should be noted that it is not specific to the right hand column. It happens on any column that has a 1 in the lowest position. I am wondering if it is because the size of the slice for 1 is too small to display as the bottom segment. IF you adjust the numbers so the max is a bit smaller, the 1 will appear since the segment is a bit taller.

Comment: Also to be noted. In Firefox, if you increase the height of the chart div, the 1 will show. And in Chrome 29.0.1547.66, if you decrease the height of the chart div, the 1 will disappear. This does point to a cause being that when the bottom segment is too short for a label, it disappears. This does not happen when the upper segments get too small however.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird That is the column I am referring to. It doesn't surprise me that the results are inconsistent across different operating systems but same browser version.

Comment: @Jack.R.Abbit Thanks for verifying, I did notice it was because the segment was too small, the segment in Firefox turns out to be 1 pixel shorter, than in Chrome. I am looking for a workaround that does not involve changing the height of the chart, or the data in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling cropping of data labels:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            crop: false
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eGW86/2/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this setting makes the dataLabels overlap when the column segments are very small.

Comment: Here's the bit of code that's hiding the labels: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/highcharts.src.js#L6431

Not sure what the solution is if forcing crop to false isn't a workaround

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is struggling with this issue (like me earlier today), as FYI, this is has been resolved by newer version of highcharts library